# How to conditionally trigger an insert or update when a specific column is updated

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Given two tables below;

```
Table name: coupon
-----+-------------+---------------------+
code | description | last_redeemed_at    |
-----+-------------+---------------------+
ABC  | lorem um... | 2022-03-05 15:57:41 |
-----+-------------+---------------------+
DEF  | who has ... | null                |
-----+-------------+---------------------+
GHI  | amazing T.. | null                |
-----+-------------+---------------------+
```

And

```
Table name: redeem
-----+-------+
code | count |
-----+-------+
ABC  | 1     |
-----+-------+
```

The trigger below can insert into the `redeem` table successfully whenever any row on the `coupon` table gets update.

```sql
-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_redeem_trigger;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_redeem_trigger
AFTER UPDATE
ON coupon FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO redeem(code, count) VALUES(OLD.code, 1);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How to insert into the `redeem` table only when the `coupon.last_redeemed_at` column get updated?

Please note that the `coupon.last_redeemed_at` column has no initial value hence *null* prior to update.

Comment: You cannot conditionally fire a trigger but you can do stuff conditionally within a trigger using IF..THEN..END IF see manual for examples.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: Add a IF statement before insert and check if INSERTED value and DELETED value of a column are different.

Comment: @Meyssam Toluie MYSQL does not have INSERTED and DELETED tables see manual link in my comment for mysql way

Comment: @P.Salmon My fault. I think it is in SQL Server.